# Rewards for rebuilding?

Tags: dnd-5e

My players reside in a recently burned down village. They brought back people to rebuild it and I'm going to allow them to chose which parts to rebuild first. Could you guys give me any rewards or advantages they'd get when they rebuild something?

Comment: Since this question is looking for idea-generation, I think you'll find much better results on a traditional forum. We have [a list of those we recommend](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) for this purpose, and I hope you find good ideas there!

Comment: You're welcome. Literally: welcome to the site! (I just noticed you're a fairly-new member.)

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions off the top of my head

**Town market**

With the new and less destroyed Town market up and running trade has returned to the bustling village of (Wherever). You can now purchase items off of the PHB while in town and vendors that are native to town will offer a (insert number here) Discount as a courtesy for you helping them rebuild.

**Inn**

Now that drinks have returned to the town adventurers and town goers alike have a place to waste time and spread gossip. Player characters can now learn of new quests and rumors. Maybe also include free rooms unless you intend on including...

**The duke/mayor/nobility mansion**

No village can be complete without a much larger and prettier house making all the peasants look small. For helping bring back a central form of government things will run a lot smoother in the village. Because of such, the villagers will like you. Though they may be reminded they need to pay taxes again so whether thats a good thing or not, time will tell.
Also the noble or whoever will let you stay in his oversized house because he likes you.

**Generic trade buildings, Smith, Cobbler, etc.**
Rebuilding any of these will net you a much greater discount than the discount that one would get from the town market. Say you could buy a steel set of armor for 200 gold. The market might sell it to you for 150. The smith would sell it to you for 100.

**Church of (Whichever deity they want)**

With the rebuilding of the church the commoners will have someone to go to in times of need. Hopefully these times of need don't involve their village being burned down again.
You can now beseech the church and their priests/clerics for uses of healing spells up to a certain level.
Also maybe that god/church likes you a bit more than not at all.

Comment: To the point of the market square. Vendors would likely charge inflated prices for items in areas that "desperately" need them. Supply and demand... until the region is stabilized at least and there is competition.